# Get post thumbnails in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code to get the image for post thumbnail, but the image is not found on the page.

Please suggest some ideas.

```
<?php 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
the_post_thumbnail();
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50);
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one to get image path and then after pass that path to image scr.

```
<?php
       $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
       $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large', true); ?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  $image_url[0];  ?>"  />
       </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to used

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

If you want to get thumbnail with custom width and height then used below code

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array( 100, 100) );
```

In array first element for width and second for height.

Answer (score 1):

try to pass post id in function

```
 $post_id = get_the_ID();
 get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro

First Method:

```
<?php
       $imgId = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
       $imgUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgId,'your image size', true);
?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  $imgUrl[0];  ?>" /></a>
```

Second Method:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'your image size' );
```

Hope you find your solution